# Ordered List in sidebar not showing numbers

Tags: css

I have a sidebar with an ordered list and the numbers are not showing up.

I've checked the style sheets and have even added list-style-type: decimal!important to the element to force them to show with no luck.

I've used Developer tools to try and track down the problem and see that the styling is being ignored but I can't seem to figure out what it causing the trouble.

Could someone take a look an help me find the problem?

http://lose21poundsin21days.com/

Comment: update the link, its gives 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:block` from your `style.css` in `line-number 241`..

in `.sidebar-widget li` class....

and your problem will be solved...